# Posting data from HTML form to Google Sheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script

Hi,

I want to submit this form to a Google sheet :

```
<form action="link_to_google_script" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_blank" onsubmit="">
    First:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:200px"><br>
    Last:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" style="width:200px"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

The Google Script is :

```
function doPost(e) {
    // Sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id_of_the_sheet");
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    // Timestamp
    var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow([
        timestamp,
        e.parameter.firstname,
        e.parameter.lastname]);
    return false;
}
```

It works BUT, sends an error message ("The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type."). Could anyone explain me how to prevent this? This there a way I could call a function in the script when the form is submitted?

**EDIT**: I found a way to do it.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby9GRGPdEXhwT5OEJ9kf8Qt8OgC7pdni8R1GyXABNnKqBN4AHw/exec">
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" style="width:200px"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" style="width:200px"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit">
</form>

<!-- This is where the confirmation message goes after submission -->
<p><span id="myConf">This is where the confirmation message will appear after submission.</span></p>
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // References:
    var $form = $('#myForm');
    var $conf = $('#myConf');
    var $subm = $('#mySubmit');
    var $impt = $form.find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden');
 // Submit function:
    $form.submit(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
      // On success, clear all inputs;
            $impt.val('').attr('value','').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
   // Write a confirmation message:
            $conf.html("Submitted!");
   // Disable the submit button:
            $subm.prop('disabled', true);
        },'json');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to comeback and share that you found a solution. This it's better done by posting the solution as an answer. Ref. [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)