# Scripts: Need to export/copy data from Google Sheet to another (acting as a form submission)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

For a quick background, I'm using a single google sheet as a daily "dashboard" for my managers' shift reports.  I'm using a few time driven scripts to export each report to pdf and email it to our ops team every night, and another script to clear the data so the report is ready for the next day.

This works well for day-to-day review, but we lack the capability to store daily stats we want to reference months-years down the road.  We used Google Forms for this in the past, but I'm determined that we can consolidate both processes.

As imaged, the circled fields on the "dashboard" sheet are the data points I want to export to an archive sheet.  Ideally, the data would export to a spreadsheet adding 1 row of MB data followed by CAD data in the next row.

[image]

I've played around with a few scripts playing with 'HTML Google Form Submissions', but I couldn't find a solution which could pull in data from another sheet.  To make this work, I would need to be able to reference specific cells/ranges as entries to specific form questions.

I've also tried some scripts which copied data to the next empty row of another sheet similar to Google Forms, but it became super buggy and difficult to fine tune.

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML Google Form Submissions"?

Comment: Please read [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  By 'HTML g f s..., I'm referring to a similar process as shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358816/posting-data-from-html-form-to-google-sheet .  My thought was that I could tweak that script to populate a form submission to reference cells from my source sheet instead of the pre-filled text used in the example.

Comment: Also, I've read 'Extending Google Sheets' and am familiar with most of the concepts - I do not see anything there that can help me.

Comment: The referred Q isn't about Google Forms, it's about an HTML Form and Google Apps Script. If you want help with that, create a [mcve] and add the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are asking for.

```
    function backup(){
      var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a7:g8").getValues();
      var backupss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("backupsheeturl");
      var backupsheet = backupss.getSheetByName("backupsheet");
      backupsheet.appendRow(data[0]).appendRow(data[1]);
    }
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This gets the data to the 'backupsheet', but it does not allow for repeat submissions to be stored.  I worked around this borrowing from a script designed to enter data after the last row as follows:

Comment: function copytestdata() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Report (Beta)");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  sheet1.getRange("B96:I97").copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7), {contentsOnly:true});
 }

Comment: This is currently doing what I need - I will do some more tinkering to see if I run into any issues.  Thanks again